# PhantomJs can't render a specific page from source

Tags: phantomjs

I have been successfully able to take raw html (that has been retrieved with another product) then have phantomjs take that raw html and render the full page including running any/all javascript. I recently encountered a page that was not having its javascript rendered.

This is how I run it...

```
phantomjs myscript.js > OUTPUT.txt 2>&1
```

Here is the myscript.js file that demonstrates the issue...

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
var system = require('system');
var address = 'http://cloud.firebrandtech.com/#!/login';
var rawHtml = '<!DOCTYPE html>\
<html>\
<head>\
    ﻿<meta charset="utf-8">\
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">\
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">\
<meta name="description" content="Web Portal for managing Cloud Products, Assets, and Distributions">\
<meta name="author" content="Firebrand Technologies">\
<title>Firebrand Cloud</title>\
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/widgets/css/widgets.css">\
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/portal.css">\
</head>\
<body ng-app="portal" fc-app="cloud" fc-direct="true" class="fc">\
    <div>\
        <div data-ng-if="user.isLoaded" data-ng-controller="PortalCtrl">\
            <div data-ng-include="getView()"></div>\
            <div class="container">\
                <div data-ui-view></div>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
    <script src="/widgets/js/widgets.js"></script>﻿\
<script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>\
<script src="/js/portal.js"></script>\
</body>\
</html>';

page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
page.setContent(rawHtml, address);
window.setTimeout(function () {
    if(page.content.indexOf('Sign In') > -1)
        console.log('YAY!!! Javascript Rendered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    else
        console.log('BOO!!! Javascript NOT Rendered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')     

    phantom.exit();
}, 5000);
```

Seems like this page requires some auth/cors to work. I can get it to work if phantomjs makes the actual request (using page.open) to get the source like the following example. However, this solution will not work for me. Phantomjs has to use the source like in the example above (which like I mentioned, has been working great for all other sites).

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
var system = require('system');
var address = 'http://cloud.firebrandtech.com/#!/login ';

page.open(address, function(status) {  
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(page.content.indexOf('Sign In') > -1)
            console.log('YAY!!! Javascript Rendered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
        else
            console.log('BOO!!! Javascript NOT Rendered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')     

        phantom.exit();
    }, 5000)  
});
```

I have already tried using flags like the following but they seem to have no effect...

```
phantomjs --web-security=false --ignore-ssl-errors=true thefilebelow.js > OUTPUT.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working...

Since I used another product (not phantomjs) to retrieve the page source, I needed to persist the cookies sent back with that request. Then I had to pass in those cookies using [addCookie](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/add-cookie.html) like so...

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
var system = require('system');
var address = 'http://cloud.firebrandtech.com/#!/login';
var rawHtml = 'same raw html as above...';

//THE NEXT 3 LINES ARE WHAT CHANGED
var cookiesFromInitialRequest = [{name: 'aaa', value: 'bbb', domain: 'ccc'}, etc...]
for(var i = 0; i < cookiesFromInitialRequest.length; i++)
    phantom.addCookie(cookiesFromInitialRequest[i])

page.settings.resourceTimeout = 5000;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
page.setContent(rawHtml, address);
window.setTimeout(function () {
    if(page.content.indexOf('Sign In') > -1)
        console.log('YAY!!! Javascript Rendered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
    else
        console.log('BOO!!! Javascript NOT Rendered!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')     

    phantom.exit();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: So... is this the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, i just can't select it as the answer until tomorrow.